# WPF Textblock Distorted Text

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm facing a strange issue on one of my computer. The problem is related to how text is being rendered on two different computers.

I'll start by sharing two screenshots. One is correct version followed by the problematic one.
[image]

[image]

Here you can see the text distortion in later screenshot.

Following is the XAML. Sections "CountdownView" and "MessageView" are visible, and "Response Indicator" is hidden in both cases. Verdana Font is bound to both textblocks.

```
        <!--PollingInfoView-->
    <Grid 
        x:Name="PollingInfoView"
        Width="auto" Height="auto" 
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"

        >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.67*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush
                    Color="{Binding Path=PollingInfoBackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Opacity="{Binding Path=PollingInfoBackgroundOpacity, Mode=OneWay}"
                >

            </SolidColorBrush>
        </Grid.Background>



        <!--CountdownView-->
        <Grid Width="auto" Height="auto" >

            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="auto" Height="auto" >

                <Border x:Name="ResponsiveIndicator" Visibility="Hidden" Background="DarkRed"  Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbResponseIndicatorText" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="{Binding Path=PollingInfoForegroundColor, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               Width="auto" Height="auto" 
                               Margin="0,3,0,3"
                               FontFamily="{Binding Path=PollingInfoFontFamily, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12"                                    
                               >
                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="{Binding Path=DropShadowColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              Opacity="{Binding Path=DropShadowOpacity, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              BlurRadius="{Binding Path=DropShadowBlurRadius, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              Direction="240"
                                              ShadowDepth="{Binding Path=DropShadowDepth, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              >

                            </DropShadowEffect>

                        </TextBlock.Effect>



                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>

            </Viewbox>

        </Grid>
        <!--MessageView-->
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Width="auto" Height="auto" >
            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="auto" Height="auto" >
                <Grid 
                    Width="auto" Height="auto" 
                    x:Name="MessageView">
                    <TextBlock Name="tbMessage" 
                               TextAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="{Binding Path=PollingInfoForegroundColor, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               FontSize="32"          
                               Width="auto" Height="auto" 
                               FontFamily="{Binding Path=PollingInfoFontFamily, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               Text="Please Vote Now"
                               >
                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="{Binding Path=DropShadowColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              Opacity="{Binding Path=DropShadowOpacity, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              BlurRadius="{Binding Path=DropShadowBlurRadius, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              Direction="240"
                                              ShadowDepth="{Binding Path=DropShadowDepth, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              >

                            </DropShadowEffect>

                        </TextBlock.Effect>

                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>

        <!--Response Indicator-->
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Width="auto" Height="auto" >
            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="auto" Height="auto" >
                <Grid 
            x:Name="CountdownView"
                    Width="auto" Height="auto" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock Name="tbCountDown" Visibility="Hidden" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                    
                               Foreground="{Binding Path=PollingInfoForegroundColor, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               FontSize="32"
                               FontFamily="{Binding Path=PollingInfoFontFamily, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               Width="auto" Height="auto" 
                               Text="5"
                               >
                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="{Binding Path=DropShadowColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              Opacity="{Binding Path=DropShadowOpacity, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              BlurRadius="{Binding Path=DropShadowBlurRadius, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              Direction="240"
                                              ShadowDepth="{Binding Path=DropShadowDepth, Mode=OneWay}"
                                              >

                            </DropShadowEffect>

                        </TextBlock.Effect>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Note: The screen resolution of the computer having trouble is: 1366x768. It's Windows 7 Enterprise edition with "Intel(R) HD Graphics Family" Display adaptors. Though I've couldn't reproduce the issue on another computer with 1366x768 resolution, however, that computer has different Display drivers installed.

Any solution, idea or hint would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Keep the second picture and sell it as modern art! No seriously, if you already realized that you can't reproduce the issue on another PC, it's going to be hard for other readers. Did you try to minimize the example (does it occur on the same PC for other XAML?)

Comment: It doesn't occur on same PC for other XAML as you can see XAML under "MessageView" comment.

Comment: Did you already set up a new project on the faulty PC and copy the clean XAML over, getting same problems?